# highgui and videocapture libraries missing in OpenCV 3.0

Tags: video-capture, opencv3.0, highgui

I was trying to compile OpenCV 3.0 in java netbeans but there was an error:
**package org.opencv.highgui does not exist**
After a bit of research I came to know the jar file of OpenCV 3.0 doesn't include highgui. 
Can anyone help me what should I do if I want to include highgui and VideoCapture libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OpenCV 2.7. It has both highgui and video capturing librarire intact.

Comment: there is no such thing as opencv2.7

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV 3 has a new package that includes every single module. In CPP It is called `opencv_world300.dll` and in java it is simply `opencv-300.jar`

You only have to include this package and you will be able to use all of opencv's functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I started using `OpenCV 4.1` and found some code from an earlier version where `Highgui` and `videoCapture` weren't working. I found out it was because the import name changed.

The new ones are `org.opencv.highgui.HighGui` and `org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture`

This could have been a similar problem.